# google indexing pages behind age restriction form

Tags: cookies, web-crawler, google-search-console

I have an age restriction form that requires filling in before users can pass. It writes a cookie and if the users has not filled it on they always get sent back to the user form.

In webmaster tools it only shows up as indexing 1 page - is there any way to allow google to crawl all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

Most web crawlers do NOT know how to post forms, and store/resend cookies. What you can do is check the user agent string of the http request and if it matches one of [googlebot's](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Googlebot/) known user agent strings then do not redirect it back to the age form.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up it was taking the meta description  from an old DMOZ listing.

The following meta tag makes the site ignore the DMOZ entry.